# Add prefix to a specific value of an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to add a url prefix to a value in an array:

As an example, the array `$cars`:

Current array:

```
     array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'image' => string '1.jpg' (length=5)
          'car' => string 'bmw' (length=12)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'image' => string '2.jpg' (length=5)
          'car' => string 'mercedes' (length=17)
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'image' => string '3.jpg' (length=5)
          'car' => string 'bentley' (length=9)
```

I want to add the prefix in the image key.

Result should be looks like this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'image' => string 'http://cars.com/1.jpg' (length=5)
      'car' => string 'bmw' (length=12)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'image' => string 'http://cars.com/2.jpg' (length=5)
      'car' => string 'mercedes' (length=17)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'image' => string 'http://cars.com/3.jpg' (length=5)
      'car' => string 'bentley' (length=9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop on the array. [Sandbox with tests](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8de997f4a3083a1b1722e5476c5c88cf287395c7)

Using foreach:

```
foreach ($arr as $i => $a) {
   $arr[$i]['image'] = 'http://cars.com/' . $arr[$i]['image'];
}
```

Using foreach with reference:

```
foreach ($arr as &$a) {
   $a['image'] = 'http://cars.com/' . $a['image'];
}
```

Using for:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
   $arr[$i]['image'] = 'http://cars.com/' . $arr[$i]['image'];
}
```

Using array_walk:

```
array_walk($arr3,  function(&$v) { 
    $v['image'] = 'http://cars.com/' . $v['image'];
});
```

Using while:

```
$i = count($arr) - 1;
while ($i > 0) {
   $arr[$i]['image'] = 'http://cars.com/' . $arr[$i]['image'];
   $i--;
}
```

Comment: All the answers helped me, but I believe that is the most complete answer. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your out array might be called $cars, how about...

```
foreach ($cars AS $key => $car) {
  $cars[$key]['image'] = 'http://cars.com/' . $car['image'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @IncredibleHat! Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can cycle the array using foreach (or for) or you can literally walk the array using array_walk function and alter each item:

```
array_walk($cars, function(&$item) {
    $item['image'] = "http://cars.com/".$item['image'];
});
```